# Javascript count keys in braces of function

Tags: javascript, key, braces

I call a function like so:

```
update_insert('information',{
    element_id: 1,
    type: 'menu',
    info: 'Hi how are ya?',
    new_window: ''
});
```

The function is:

```
function update_insert(table,data){
    alert(data.length);
}
```

I am trying to get the number of keys that I inserted into the function, and eventually get the names of the keys, dynamically with a loop. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objects don't have the .length attribute like arrays do in JavaScript. You'll need to use a function to count the number of items in an object:

```
getObjectLength = function(obj) {

    var size = 0, key;

    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
            size++;
    }

    return size;
}
```

**EDIT:**

And to get the keys from an object:

```
getObjectKeys = function(obj) {

    var keys = [];

    for (var key in obj) {
        keys.push(key);
    }

    return keys;
}
```

Comment: What about getting the property names?

Comment: Or on newer browsers (or if you include an ES5 shim), `Object.keys(obj).length`.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: The keys are supplied as `key` in the loop.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Well *I* know that, but does the OP? (see my answer...)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the keys with the following function (which is safe to use in older browsers)...

```
var getObjectKeys = function(obj) {

    if (Object.keys && typeof Object.keys == "function") {
        return Object.keys(obj);
    }

    var prop, keys = [];

    for (prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            keys.push(prop);
        }
    }

    return keys;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wPcSn/).

Alternatively, use `Object.keys()` and use an equivalent `[shim][2]` for older browsers.

You can check the `length` property of the returned `Array` to determine the amount of keys.

---

If you want to dredge up all enumerable properties on the prototype chain, you can use...

```
var getObjectKeysIncludingInherited = function(obj) {
    var keys = [],
        i = 0;

    for (keys[i++] in obj);

    return keys;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YCt4N/).

---

Alternatively, you may *really want* to use the `length` property of an object to do it, but **please don't**. It's considered somewhat dangerous to augment native JavaScript objects, and it's kind of confusing (`Object`s don't have a `length` property but `Array`s do) and it won't work in older browsers...

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "length", {
    get: function() {
        return Object.keys(this).length;
    }        
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CDS7c/).

Comment: to get the count of keys...use `Object.keys(data).length`

Comment: Hey. Thanks for all the help guys. I you answered so quickly! In the meantime I found exactly what i was looking for:

$.each(data, function(index, value) { 
    alert(index + ': ' + value); 
});

Comment: @IlyaKarnaukhov: Ah, yes, that's a jQuery thing. If you're asking a client-side JavaScript question and you're using jQuery (or another library), be sure to include both the `javascript` tag **and** the tag for the library (in this case `jquery`), so people can point you at something in the library if relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
function update_insert(table,data){
    var dataLength = 0, keys = [];

    for(prop in data) {
        if(data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            dataLength++;
            keys.push(prop);
        }
    }
}
```

Arrays are actually objects which have a custom `length` property (and some other stuff `:P`) so not all objects have a `length` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = new Array();

for(name in data)
{
  if(data.hasOwnProperty(name))
  {
    names.push(name); 
  }
}

names.length - will give you what you need.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var keys = [];
for(var k in data) {
  if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(data, k)) {
    keys.push(data[k]);
  }
}
k.length //size of keys
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are a jQuery fan or potential user:

```
var size = 0;

$.each(obj, function(key, value) {
    alert('key = ' + key);
    alert('value = ' + value);
    size++;
});

alert(size);
```